Connecting MacBook Pro to Samsung 49" 5K Monitor
I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) and a Samsung LS49CG934SUXUF monitor. I want to achieve the most efficient and effective way to transfer the display between these two devices.
According to Samsung's website, the monitor supports a resolution of 5120 x 1440 and a refresh rate of 240 Hz. The monitor has 1 DisplayPort 1.4, 1 HDMI 2.1, and 1 Micro HDMI 2.1 input. The MacBook only has Thunderbolt 3 USB-C outputs. Which cables and versions of these cables should I use? What is the maximum resolution and refresh rate I can achieve?

Your Mac has DisplayPort output over USB-C. This means when properly connected to a display with a DisplayPort input, then DisplayPort signals as output through the USB-C port. This is refered to a DisplayPort alt-mode. In other words, an adaptor in not required. You probably will be limited to a 60 Hz output. An example USB-C to DisplayPort cable would be this one.

What about HDMI 2.1? Will I have any losses if I use HDMI?

There are adaptors available to convert the DisplayPort signals output from the USB-C port of the Mac to HDMI. However, there is nothing to be gained by doing so unless the display does not have a DisplayPort input. In other words, you cannot gain any additional functionality by converting to HDMI. See Belkin Connect USB-C to HDMI 2.1 Adapter.
